# Spring data rest not working properly with OrderColumn

Tags: java, spring, rest, jpa, spring-data-rest

```
package main.foo;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by mihaildoronin on 27/11/15.
 */
@Entity
public class Foo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "foo")
    @OrderColumn(nullable=false)
    private List<Bar> bars;

    private String name;

    public List<Bar> getBars() {
        return bars;
    }

    public void setBars(List<Bar> bars) {
        this.bars = bars;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
package main.foo;

import org.springframework.cglib.core.GeneratorStrategy;

import javax.annotation.Generated;
import javax.persistence.*;

/**
 * Created by mihaildoronin on 27/11/15.
 */
@Entity
public class Bar {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Foo foo;

    private String name;

    public Foo getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public void setFoo(Foo foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

When I'm trying to post bar to bars it gives me this error.

```
NULL not allowed for column \"BARS_ORDER\"; SQL statement:\ninsert into bar (id, foo_id, name) values (null, ?, ?)
```

If I would make OrderColumn nullable then I would be able to post, but wouldn't be able to GET /foos//bars resource with something saying about this column is null. Which is basically saying that spring-data-rest can't handle ordered subcollection.

Is there anything I can do with that, so that I would be able to get ordered subcollection? I mean I probably can do a linked list with couple of OneToOne relationships in bar, but this would be very bad for performance, so maybe there is another way?

Comment: Did you generate your database using the model as presented in your code? Do you have the code which is trying to insert this record: It looks like you did not assign a list to bars yet.

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen Yes, the bd schema is auto generated from this code and the code to add resource to collection is inside spring data rest library. I think I've found the place where it happens and its obvious why it's not working. The code is just saving the entity, but doesn't know anything about the fact that this entity is in many to one relationship with another entity and doesn't adding it to the list (and its this adding that is actually creates order inside hibernate)

Comment: @BohuslavBurghardt No, I am not. What I need is ability reorder the bars collection as I wish. More specifically right know I need to insert posted bar to a specific position. Like I would with bars.addAt(index, bar)

Comment: Ok, since the db schema is generated from this code, your annotation did exactly what you required it to do (create a not nullable column). The rest you now already noticed in your code :) Success.

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen My code is perfectly fine. It's spring data rest that cannot deal with ordercolumn. I was asking is there a workaround and you haven't helped with that yet. So I don't see any "success" at all.

Comment: The `@OrderColumn` was used to generate the NOT NULL constraint on the database, so it is used. AFAIK the `@OrderColumn(nullable)` is just not checked at runtime, so this behaviour is to be expected. You could set a `@Column(nullable=false) on the `id` in `bar` to get a different exception.

Comment: NotNull constraint have been generated by hibernate at startup time. Why should I "get different exception"? If I understand correctly the problem is that spring-data-rest doesn't try to add value to this column when saving posted entity and the reason for that is spring data rest doesn't trying to add  bar to the foo.bars when bar is posted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96374/discussion-between-norbert-van-nobelen-and-user1685095).